# most restrictive regular expression

Tags: regex

Let's say I have several regular expressions:

expr_1: "test_file"

expr_2: "test_*"

expr_3: "test*"

All those match the string "test_file". How can I figure out in a program which rule is the most restrictive rule( in this case expr_1 )?

What I want to achieve:

I have a general rule that applies to a lot of files, but for .jpeg files for examples, I want to do a special operation. How can I figure out that the rule which selects ".jpeg" files is more restrictive than "*" rule for example?

Edit:
I'm Using QRegExp from Qt, but this shouldn't change anything.

Comment: By number of returned results. Mostly if you are matching files.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way to solve that problem based on Language Theory:

Calculate the regexp that is the "and" or "combination" of all the other regexps.
You can convert all your regex to DFA, and then you can create the intersection of all your automatons, which will give you a new DFA that will only accept things that are accepted by all three regexps. Then you can also minimize the automaton, and convert it back to a regexp. If you do that, you'll get a regexp which is as restrictive as all the other regexps together, and which is the shortest regexp possible for doing that.

Great book that explains how to do all that: [Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321455363)

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using?

A good measure of "restriciveness" could be to run an array of potential strings (in this case, a bunch of filenames) through the regex and see how many each string matches.